# I can not add two drop down menus onto my website without one of them interfering with the other one

Tags: javascript, html

I am developing a website and I am having an issue with a drop down menu that is run via java script, interfering with another one on the same page.

I am using a template which can be found [here](http://startbootstrap.com/template-overviews/sb-admin/) (it is downloaded from bootstrap).

I want to make is so that I have two drop down menus, but when I do, the one that is located nearer the top of the code works fine, but the one that is located beneath it, has problems. Basically, when I run the website, the drop down box nearest the top works fine, but when I click, the drop down box bellow, it does not operate itself, instead it opens up the drop down box that is above it.

At first I thought it was because they both had the same id so I changed it. When I change the id though, none of them open at all.

Here is the code that is for the two drop down menu:

```
                <li>
                    <a href="javascript:;" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#demo"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-briefcase"></i> Support <i class="fa fa-fw fa-caret-down"></i></a>
                    <ul id="demo" class="collapse">
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">ProjectSend</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">Email</a>
                        </li>
                         <li>
                            <a href="#">Live Chat</a>
                        </li>
                         <li>
                            <a href="../support/tickets/">Tickets</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li> 



                <li>
                    <a href="javascript:;" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#demo"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-briefcase"></i> Developers <i class="fa fa-fw fa-caret-down"></i></a>
                    <ul id="demo" class="collapse">
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">ProjectSend</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">Email</a>
                        </li>
                         <li>
                            <a href="#">Live Chat</a>
                        </li>
                         <li>
                            <a href="../support/tickets/">Tickets</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
```

The JavaScript is referring to separate files which came from the bootstrap website.

I have also removed the second `a href="javascript"`, thinking that it mite carry on from the previous one but that did not work either,

I am relatively new to java script, and have some very basic HTML knowledge.

Thank you.

Comment: first off, you can;'t have them both with the same id, wheres the rest of the code

Comment: I think what you should do is give them different id's and change the target accordingly. See if that works.

Comment: well spotted @hatzaviv, change id of second one to demo2 and target data-target to demo2

Comment: Ahhh, guys, you are life savers. Thanks so much for your help and quick response. It is really appreciated. :)

Comment: should I write it as an answer to be chosen?

Comment: @hatzaviv Yesy, that would be good. Then I can choose it as the best answer to help anyone else having the same issue. Then they will be able to see the answer clearly. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you should do is give them different id's and change the target accordingly.

See if that works.